# Is it absolutely necessary to agitate/rotate a compost bin?

Tags: composting, apartment

I live in a small apartment with limited space (there is a small outdoor patio).

I want to start using a compost bin, but all the models I've found are quite large and seem to include mechanisms for turning or agitating the compost.

I was wondering if this was absolutely necessary to do and, if possible, could I just use a normal container of some sort and 'turn' the compost every so often when I extract the degraded soil to use?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is it you want to compost? Food leftovers?

Comment: @THelper yes - vegetable scraps mostly

Comment: I agree with J.Chomel's answer and recommend vermicomposting, unless a lot of your scraps are unsuitable to be processed by the worms. Then bokashi composting or a combination of bokashi and vermicomposting could be better. Both methods don't require turning or lots of space. Another thing to consider is what you'll do with the compost you produce.

Comment: BTW there are several related questions that may help you: [How to aerate compost without turning?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/322/99), [Is it feasible to compost in an apartment in a city like New York?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/7/99) and [Indoor composting with limited space](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2973/99)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bigger the composting pile is, the least turning it needs, because most of the pile remains sheltered from the dry / temperature-changing outside.

If you want to have a compost at your place with limited space to handle it, the best is probably to turn towards [vermicompost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermicompost). You don't need a big pile for this, and worms will do the turning for you. Great soil will come out of this in relative short time.

Another possibility is to have a big compost for the whole building. But neighbors kindness is needed for that.

Good luck!

Comment: I think that it should be mentioned that, especially for food leftovers that can get pretty soggy, aerating the compost is necessary for efficient aerobic decomposition. A pile of food leftovers left without bulky carbon-rich material and without turning risks creating an wet anaerobic layer at the bottom, that will produce a lot more CO2-equivalent by releasing extra methane (and it will probably smell bad).